# Custom response Express Validator as JSON

Tags: node.js, express, response, httpresponse

I'm using **Express Validator** for validate user req. I'm trying to create custom response like this:

```
{
    "code": 300,
    "status": false,
    "message": "Your email is not valid",
    "param": "email",
    "value": "kevin"
}
```

but what I got is

```
[
    {
        "code": 300,
        "status": false,
        "message": "Your email is not valid",
        "param": "email",
        "value": "kevin"
    }
]
```

Here is my code:

#### controller.js:

```
const errors = validationResult(req).formatWith(utils.error);
if(!errors.isEmpty()){

    res.status(300).json(errors.array());
}
```

#### ResUtils.js

```
error({msg, param, value, nestedErrors}) {
    var code = 300;
    var format = {code, status:false, message:msg, param:param, value:value, nestedErrors:nestedErrors};
    return format;
}
```

How do I can get the response as Json, without `[]`.

Thankyou.

Comment: Quick and dirty => res.status(300).json(errors.array()[0]);

Answer (score 0):

Well, this state is good in my opinion, there is possibility of multiple errors so you should process all messages in a frontend app (or mobile or whatever) to give user informations about all invalid fields (or options or whatever). If you really need only a object, you can pick a first error message from an array for example.

```
if(!errors.isEmpty()){
    const errorsArray = errors.array();
    res.status(300).json(errorsArray[0]);
}
```

But as I said it is better approach to handle all error messages.